# Why do sped up videos in Safari have terrible, tinny audio? Can it be fixed?

Tags: macos, safari, audio

I switched to Safari on Mac after Chrome was crippling Mac mini with it's memory usage. The only thing making this transition difficult is the terrible audio when videos are sped up in Safari.

I've tried Youtube and other players but the issue persists. I speed up videos very often, but Safari's terrible audio is too awful to bare. I've read that it's the only popular browser that suffers from this.

Could somebody please explain why Safari produces this hollow, tinny sound when video speed is increased?

Also, is this something that could be fixed though something like an extension, or maybe the web developers of a given site, or is it something that would require a change in the production of Safari?

Maybe "fix" is the wrong word. Maybe this is the default way sped up audio should sound and maybe other browsers put the effort in to make it sound more pleasant, but the point still stands.

Comment: I can't comment, but this appears to be an issue with WebKit, as the same issue appears in Orion Browser.

Comment: I just switched to Brave instead. I prefer keeping the apps I install to a minimum but unfortunately the robotic sound of sped up audio in Safari made using it too unpleasant. I've heard some people say they don't hear anything wrong, but to me it's very obvious and has been that way for as long as I remember. Maybe only an unlucky few can hear it? Oh well.